# Get one Array of objects mongodb

Tags: mongodb, subdocument

I have many sub documents in my collection, I only want to fetch Configuration array of objects **(not empty)** and ignore all others object

I tried one of the solution on stackoverflow [Find MongoDB records where array field is not empty (using Mongoose)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789684/find-mongodb-records-where-array-field-is-not-empty-using-mongoose)

it returns me the configuration array but also other objects of my collection

here is the sample data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0vSN.jpg

this query returns me all the configuration array of objects but it also returns me empty arrays which I do not want, any solution for this ?

```
return Company.find({}, {
  "configuration": 1
}, {
  "configuration": {
    "$not": {
      "$size": 0
    }
  }
})
```

sample data

```
configuration: [],
configuration: [],
configurtaion: [{
          "id": "2013",
          "name": "TRUEAUTO",
          "locationId": null,
          "deviceIdentifier": "850",
          "serialNumber": "",
          "modelNumber": "OptiPlex 3010",
          "tagNumber": null,
          "purchaseDate": null,
          "installationDate": "2016-07-28T00:00:00.000Z",
          "warrantyExpirationDate": null,
          "vendorNotes": null,
          "notes": null,
          "lastLoginName": null,
          "billFlag": "false",
          "backupServerName": null,
          "backupProtectedDeviceList": null,

          }
        }]
```

I want to ignore empty arrays and only to get configuration objects only

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can use $exist property with $size 

Company.find({ configuration: { $exists: true, $not: {$size: 0} } }, {
  "configuration": 1
})
//Or you can check
Company.find({'configuration.0': {$exists: true}});
```

Comment: I just tried this it give me other sub documents as well, which is not required. Please see the screen shot

Comment: Hi Shantanu; I think you have some typos in your code, for example "configurtaion" is a mistake for "configuration".

Comment: Did you try the second method