# Can Mongoose documents be auto-deleted based on specific criteria?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Notification Schema which includes an array of `recipients`. If a Notification documents' `recipients` array becomes empty, then I want it to be automatically deleted.

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible within Mongoose. I would suggest when you remove the final recipient, check if the array is empty then delete the document.
This might be a useful stack overflow post if you want to delete all documents where the recipient array is empty:
[Find MongoDB records where array field is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789684/find-mongodb-records-where-array-field-is-not-empty-using-mongoose)