# Filter a custom key or value via mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I Have a `Message` Schema with 2 type message: text and voice, How Should I get value of text?

**text data example:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8ea03d2601be24b086ccd4"),
    "userId" : 20,
    "text" : "Hi",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**voice data example:**

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a8ea03d2601be24b086ccd4"),
        "userId" : 20,
        "voice" : "d2601be24bd22601be24b",
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

**Code:**

```
Message
  .find({userId: '20'}, {_id: 0, text: ''})
  .exec((err, obj) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    for (const val of Object.values(obj)) {
      console.log(val.text);
    }
  });
```

**output:**

```
Hi    // for text
undefined  // for voice
```

I have All Type of Message in Output, How Should I get all text value? (not voice)?

Comment: `console.log(val.text ? val.text : val.voice);` can be a solution.

Comment: OP said they didn't want voice, sounds like a simple `if` statement. `if(val.text) { //do the thing; }`

Comment: not work `console.log(val.text ? val.text : val.voice);` , I have all in output again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options, you could add an if statement within your for loop e.g.

```
for (const val of Object.values(obj)) {
    if(val.text) console.log(val.text);
}
```

Alternatively you could adjust your database query to only select messages with a non-empty text string e.g.

```
Message
  .find(
    {
       userId: '20',
       text: {
           $exists: true,
           $ne: ''
    },
    {_id: 0, text: ''}
  )
```

Note: my query may not be quite right as I didn't test it, but it would be something to that effect. See: [Find MongoDB records where array field is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789684/find-mongodb-records-where-array-field-is-not-empty) for similar concept.