# In MongoDB how to use $lookup to get not matched records only?

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregate-functions

In Mongodb, I want to get data of those products who don't have any order.

Collections : **master_product_details, master_order_details**

I'm using normal $lookup query which is giving all records of matched or unmatched with order.

```
db.master_product_details.aggregate([
        { 
        $match: { seller_user_id : 'seller_id' } 
        },
        {
        $lookup : {from: "master_order_details",localField: "seller_sku_id", foreignField: "sku_id", as : "Orders"} 
        },
        {$unwind : '$Orders'},
        {$project : { seller_sku_id : 1, product_title : 1, _id : 0}

            }
        ])
```

Any other way to get result ?

Comment: use one more `$match` condition at the end. `{ $match: { Orders: [] }}`

Comment: Yes, Thank you @AnthonyWinzlet, I just replace {$unwind : '$Orders'}, with   { $match: { Orders: [] }} and got my desired result.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use one more `$match` condition at the end of the pipeline

```
db.master_product_details.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "seller_user_id": "seller_id" }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "master_order_details",
    "localField": "seller_sku_id",
    "foreignField": "sku_id",
    "as": "Orders"
  }},
  { "$match": { "Orders": [] }}
])
```

Comment: In case you needed only matching records(as was case with our requirements), the second match condition would have been: 
    { "$match": { "Orders": { $exists: true, $ne: [] } } }
courtesy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789684/find-mongodb-records-where-array-field-is-not-empty