# Filtering aggregation with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I need to filter this query so that documents with value `Undefined` does not appear. Currently, my code shows this result:

```
db.getCollection("actors").find({})

db.actors.aggregate([
    {
        $group: { _id: "$cast", Peliculas: { $sum: 1 } },
    },
    { $sort: { Peliculas: -1 } },
    { $limit: 2 }
])
```

[image]

I need some filter that makes `Undefined` disappear so that it shows me as the first value: `Harold Lloyd`.

I have previously performed the following operation:

```
//unwind
    db.getCollection("Tarea").find({})
    fase1 = { $unwind: "$cast"}
    etapas = [fase1]
    db.Tarea.aggregate( etapas )

    //out
    fase1 = { $unwind: "$cast" }
    query2 = { "_id": 0 }
    fase2 = { $project: query2 }
    fase3 = { $out: "actors" }
    etapas = [ fase1, fase2, fase3 ]
    db.Tarea.aggregate( etapas )
```

And now I have a new collection called 'actors'.

Comment: Could you share the sample json?

Comment: Sure. The json is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VKuhce2ofjLjYEoND_Fz2wqcYHAf6kkZ/view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find MongoDB records where array field is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789684/find-mongodb-records-where-array-field-is-not-empty)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

[Sample live demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1zL9I7HJzU0)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      cast: {
        $exists: true,
        $not: {
          $size: 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$cast",
      Peliculas: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      Peliculas: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 2
  }
])
```

Reference

[Mongodb - $match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

[Mongodb - $size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

[Mongodb - $exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

Comment: Thank you all. Maybe I haven't expressed myself well. What I need exactly is this:

On actors, get a top list of the actors who have participated in more films ((t is fine to limit it to only one, since that parameter can be modified), without deleting undefined records, but filtering them so that they simply do not appear in the query.

I want them to continue appearing as Undefined, but not to appear as top actors who have participated in the film. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@hbamithkumara answer will work perfectly if you want to eliminate all the records where `cast array is empty`. But if you want to also display the count `Peliculas` for all the `empty cast array` with default text like `No Cast`, you can try this

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZZJGnTLn2hx)

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      cast: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$cast",
              []
            ]
          },
          then: [
            "No Cast"
          ],
          else: "$cast"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$cast",
      Peliculas: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result would be like

```
   [
  {
    "Peliculas": 1,
    "_id": [
      "Paul Boyton"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Peliculas": 1,
    "_id": [
      "Ching Ling Foo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Peliculas": 21,
    "_id": [
      "No Cast"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I thought it is not necessary since it is mentioned *I need some filter that makes Undefined disappear* in the question.

Comment: Your answer is correct and works but it's just another option available that might come handy in some other use case.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it adding this line to the code:

```
{$match: {cast:{$ne:"Undefined"}}}
```

So now the complete code looks like:

```
db.actors.aggregate([
{$match: {cast:{$ne:"Undefined"}}},
{$group : {_id: "$cast", total : {$sum: 1 }}},
{$sort:{total:-1}},
{$limit:5}])
```

and I can see the top 5 actors list without Undefined:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrJwT.png)

Thank you all.