# Mongodb How to filter a Document as not to pass fields with empty in the next stage in pipeline in Aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this:

```
{
 _id:'5e2b8a2065318f95166deedc'
 expenses:[{amount:100},{amount:200}]
},
{
 _id:'5e2b8a2065318f95166deedc'
 expenses:[]
},
{
 _id:'5e2b8a2065318f95166deedc'
 expenses:[{amount:400},{amount:600}]
}
```

I need to query with aggregate to return the fields WITH EXPENSES, that is expenses with empty array should not be returned to the next step of the pipeline

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Exps.aggregate([

    {$match: {"id":ObjectId(myId)}},

    {$group:{
        _id:'$_id',
        expenses:{$last:"$expenses"},
    }}
   ])
```

But this returns all three subdocuments including the empty one. How can I just get the 1st and 3rd subdocuments (as per my example) so that i can pass them to the next step on the pipeline?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/

Comment: @DanielF Could you please show me the actual code on how to handle my problem above using the two links you've provided above?

Comment: @Amani : This is already answered, please check it there..

Comment: @whoami I have checked and it really solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `expenses` has one or more entries, then `expenses.1` will exist. Therefore the following would work.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "expenses.1": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hkti0Fj8U3I

Or by using `size` together with `not`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "expenses": {
        $not: {
          $size: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/EpYDtEBf0yk

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789684/find-mongodb-records-where-array-field-is-not-empty which was pointed to me in the comments, solved my problem. Thanks