# Removing empty records from $filter

Tags: mongodb, express, mongodb-query, nosql

I have recently started using mongodb queries. I am following along the mongodb tutorial and I am using $project and $filter query to get specific set of records like this -

The records -

```
{
   _id: 0,
   items: [
     { item_id: 43, quantity: 2, price: 10 },
     { item_id: 2, quantity: 1, price: 240 }
   ]
}
{
   _id: 1,
   items: [
     { item_id: 23, quantity: 3, price: 110 },
     { item_id: 103, quantity: 4, price: 5 },
     { item_id: 38, quantity: 1, price: 300 }
   ]
}
{
    _id: 2,
    items: [
       { item_id: 4, quantity: 1, price: 23 }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code -

```
db.sales.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         items: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$items",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $gte: [ "$$item.price", 100 ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

This naturally returns all the records which have price greater than 100 in the items array and returns an empty array otherwise,like this -

```
{
   "_id" : 0,
   "items" : [
      { "item_id" : 2, "quantity" : 1, "price" : 240 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "items" : [
      { "item_id" : 23, "quantity" : 3, "price" : 110 },
      { "item_id" : 38, "quantity" : 1, "price" : 300 }
   ]
}
{ "_id" : 2, "items" : [ ] }
```

How can I get rid of the empty array record? I just want the valid records.

Comment: You can add a `$match` stage after the `$project` - filter documents with size of `ìtems` array is greater than zero.

Comment: Could you please tell me the syntax? I am extremely new to this and need a bit of hand holding. So it'll be something like { $match:{arrayInfo **something here?**}}?

Comment: [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) aggregation array operator returns the array length.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find MongoDB records where array field is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789684/find-mongodb-records-where-array-field-is-not-empty) In this link it's given with `.find()` all you need to take this find's filter part & wrap in `$match` like :: `{$match : findsFilterPart }`

Comment: @whoami,this does the job perfectly. Thankyou very much!