# MongoDB- find document by id then group it with key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

---

My Data-Structure looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "title": "Yamaha",
    "data": "Sed ut perspiciatis",
    "type": "Bike"
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "title": "Pulsar",
    "data": "Quis autem vel eum",
    "type": "Bike"
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "title": "Tesla Model Y",
    "data": "because it is pleasure",
    "type": "Car"
  },
  {
    "_id": "4",
    "title": "Harley-Davidson",
    "data": "praising pain was born",
    "type": "Bike"
  },
  {
    "_id": "6",
    "title": "Mustang",
    "data": "non numquam eius",
    "type": "Car"
  },
  {
    "_id": "7",
    "title": "BMW",
    "data": "Man of Culture",
    "type": "Car"
  }
]
```

---

Now, **From FrontEnd** Users Can Search any of the **item** from database using their **unique `_id`**, Like this:

```
db.collection.find({_id: "3" })
```

**Which returns the following:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "data": "because it is pleasure",
    "title": "Tesla Model Y",
    "type": "Car"
  }
]
```

---

**Question Part:**

Now, Including the above-returned document, I also want to return those **documents** which have it's the matching **`type`** value.

---

My Questions means that;  if the user is finding any document with their particular `_id`. let's suppose **3** then it should return the following:

Find the Item with their **Unique `_id`** and ****`$group`** the `type` field** Value

```
  [{
    "_id": "3",
    "title": "Tesla Model Y",
    "data": "because it is pleasure",
    "type": "Car"
  }
  {
    "_id": "6",
    "title": "Mustang",
    "data": "non numquam eius",
    "type": "Car"
  },
  {
    "_id": "7",
    "title": "BMW",
    "data": "Man of Culture",
    "type": "Car"
  }]
```

Is that possible to do? Is that possible to **`$group`** the document after `finding By Id` ?. I've tried Several Ways to make it but each of them is useless. Any Suggestions will be HelpFul for this complicated **Requirement**

**:)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query

- lookup with it self, join only with the type that the id=3 has.
- empty join results => different type so they are filtered out

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KnKpOBZYJy7)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        "type": "$type"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$_id",
                    "3"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$type",
                    "$type"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "joined"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$ne": [
          "$joined",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "joined"
    ]
  }
])
```

Comment: Holly crap, I never thought anyone would spend the time to do that! :D Even though I'd say it's an awful query that would be extremely slow (as it creates an object for each entry and then filters it by comparison), kudos for the time spend writing it :)

Comment: its collection scan, but the lookup can use index. I dont think we can do it with 1 query and without collection scan because we dont know what we are looking for.

Comment: @Takis_ Thanks for the answer. But the second **$match** stage **(** after the `$lookup` **)** not showing any results in MongoDB Atlas `Aggegration Pipeline Builder`. But it's working in the playground. Why?

Comment: @Takis_ I've also seen this solution: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25142571/16702515), But Second **$match** doesn't working.  Have you any idea ?

Comment: i dont know, i tested it on my driver and after on playground

Comment: @Takis_ Look, Here's 4 Image Source. It's works well for **$lookup** but not after that any stages.  **`$lookup`:** [Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3roic.png), [Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ey5R.png) . But for `$match` after **$lookup** not returning [Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZyvZ.png) and [Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Br5U.png)

Comment: you have to check the version, i think its the $unset, replace it with `{$project : {"joined" : 0}}`

Comment: @Takis_ The problem is with `{"$match": { "$expr": { "$ne" : [ "$joined" ,[] ]}} }`. $unset and $project is fine. I've tested it. Any idea ;(

Comment: @Takis_ I've exactly Copied and Pasted the aggregation and imported it into `Text to Pipeline`. And the version I'm using is **4.4.8**

Comment: i cant think of a reason, if the join works and the joined is not always empty, you should get results,  the match could be written also like  `{"$match" : { "joined": { $ne: [] } }}` but i dont think this is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You're basically mixing two separate queries:

1. Get an item by ID - returns a **single** item
2. Get a list of items, that have the same type as the type of the first item - returns a **list of items**

Because of the difference of the queries, there's no super straightforward way to do so. Surely you can use [$aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to do the trick, but logic wise you'd still query quite a bit from the database, and you'd have to dig deeper to optimize it properly.

As long as you're not querying tens of millions of records, I'd suggest you do the two queries one after another, for the sake of simplicity.